# External CSS background-image not showing

Tags: css, background-image

I have an issue with the background-image property in an external CSS file. I can't seem to get the image to show up. Its been while since I have coded so maybe it's just me forgetting everything I know but I'm pretty sure I have the link right. The website is set up like this

```
/Root/
   index.html
   /styles/
      webstyles.css
      /img/
         header.jpg
```

The background works when I use it inline so it's starting to annoy me.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MYSITE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/webstyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="headerBar">
            <h1 class="Hlogo">Title</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background:#999999;
}
headerBar
{
    background: url(/styles/img/header.jpg);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this style is in `webstyles.css`, then you need to use this way.

```
.headerBar{
    background: url('img/header.jpg');
}
```

Based on the folder structure, `"styles/img/header.jpg"` is still a wrong path.

And also, I'm not sure why, but you are missing `.` for CSS class selector when selecting the `headerBar`. Fix that one too.

Comment: It was the class selector. I don't know how I missed that, so I'm going to hide my head in shame now. Thanks for the help, and the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
background: url("styles/img/header.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.headerBar
{
    background: url("styles/img/header.jpg");
}
```

since `styles` folder is the same level as your HTML file.

---

However, if your `img` folder is not placed inside `styles` folder (which makes more sense), then you want this path instead:

```
.headerBar
{
    background: url('img/header.jpg');
}
```

Also you're missing `.` to target class `.headerBar`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`background: url(/styles/img/header.jpg);`

with

`background: url('img/header.jpg');`